# By using Ekcalendar how can we delete Particular events by clicking delete action

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

By using EventKit i can add events to iphone calendar and i can make a new calendar by using EkCalendar. But now reqirement is need to delete single events in iphone calendar. how can i do this. Thanks in advance

```
func retrieveYourCalendar() {
    let calendars = eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityType.Event)

    if(yourReminderCalendar == nil) {
        for calendar in calendars {
            if calendar.title == "new" {
                yourReminderCalendar = (calendar as EKCalendar)
                //  Exist = true
                break
            }
        }

        if(yourReminderCalendar == nil) {
            yourReminderCalendar = EKCalendar(forEntityType: EKEntityType.Event, eventStore: eventStore)
            yourReminderCalendar!.title = "new"
            yourReminderCalendar!.source = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents.source
          //  var error: NSError?
            do {
                try eventStore.saveCalendar(yourReminderCalendar!, commit: true)
                // self.calendarIdentifier = yourReminderCalendar!.calendarIdentifier
                print("Event calender saved")

            }
            catch(_){}
        }
    }






}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While adding Events to the calendar, store **eventIdentifier** in your db or any storage. It will be useful to identify the particular event to delete.

By using following code you can delete the event based on identifier,

**Objective C:**

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init]; 
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
  if (!granted) return;
  EKEvent* eventToRemove = [store eventWithIdentifier:savedEventId];
  if (eventToRemove) {
    NSError* err = nil;
    [store removeEvent:eventToRemove span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
  }
}];
```

**Swift:** Fetching events based on start date and end date.

```
// Create an Event Store instance
let eventStore = EKEventStore();
eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion: {
            (accessGranted: Bool, error: NSError?) in
            
            if accessGranted == true {
                var startDate=NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(-60*60*24)

        var endDate=NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60*24*3)

        var predicate2 = eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, calendars: nil)



        println("startDate:\(startDate) endDate:\(endDate)")

        var eV = eventStore.eventsMatchingPredicate(predicate2) as [EKEvent]!



        if eV != nil {

eventStore.removeEvent(eV, span:EKSpanFutureEvents, commit:true, error:&error)
}

            } else {
                return
            }
        })
```

Check the updated answer for swift. 
**FYI**: I didn't tested the code for swift.

Comment: This is Objective-C can you give swift code for me @rjv Kumar

Comment: plz help anyone here @EricD

Comment: @sreeji44 check my updated answer for swift. Hope this helps.